# How to display a user's bio (not the author or logged in user)

Tags: description

I'd like to (in php) display a given user's avatar and bio (description) and some social media for them (based on their profile info fields). For example, on Page1, display user Walt Whitman's (user number 9999) picture, description (bio), and social media links, regardless of who wrote the page or who is logged in reading the page.

I can display the avatar:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( 'useremail@gmail.cam', 32 ); ?>
```

I've tried a couple of things, but they don't work. I get either a full display of all meta or a fatal error (various fatal errors like 'must be string' etc).

```
<?php the_user_meta( 'description' ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $userdata = get_user_meta( 9999 ); ?><?php echo $userdata['description']; ?>
```

If I use

```
<?php $user = wp_get_current_user( 9999 ); if ( $user->exists() ) // is_user_logged_in() is a wrapper for this line $userdata = get_user_meta( $user->data->ID ); ?><pre><?php var_dump( $userdata ); ?></pre><?php echo $userdata['description'] ; ?>
```

I get a fatal error.

Comment: Do you have the user ID of the user you'd like to display these details for?

Comment: Yes, I have the user ID and the email

Comment: It looks like there's some HTML code missing in your snippet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of

- [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) or
- [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/get_currentuserinfo) (*to which `wp_get_current_user()` is a wrapper function to*) or
- [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) which uses `wp_get_current_user()`

to get the current logged in user ID.

One way or the other, you need to make sure that you have a logged in user (*user ID is not 0*) before trying to get the user's metadata from the db.

Once you have the user ID, you can use [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) to return the user's info from the db

### EXAMPLE:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $user->exists() ) { // is_user_logged_in() is a wrapper for this line
    $userdata = get_user_meta( $user->data->ID );
    ?><pre><?php var_dump( $userdata ); ?></pre><?php
}
```

### EDIT

This is very basic PHP. Here is what is returned by

```
$userdata = get_user_meta( 1 );
    ?><pre><?php var_dump( $userdata ); ?></pre><?php
```

The `var_dump()`

```
array(29) {
  ["first_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Pieter"
  }
  ["last_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Goosen"
  }
  ["nickname"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "pietergoosen"
  }
  ["description"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(349) "My naam is Pieter Goosen BLAH BLAH BLAH"
  }
  ["rich_editing"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["comment_shortcuts"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["admin_color"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "fresh"
  }
  ["use_ssl"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["show_admin_bar_front"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["wp_capabilities"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}"
  }
  ["wp_user_level"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  ["dismissed_wp_pointers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(143) "wp330_toolbar,wp330_saving_widgets,wp340_choose_image_from_library,wp340_customize_current_theme_link,wp350_media,wp360_revisions,wp390_widgets"
  }
  ["show_welcome_panel"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["wp_user-settings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(120) "libraryContent=browse&imgsize=full&align=right&editor=html&hidetb=1&mfold=o&unfold=1&urlbutton=post&posts_list_mode=list"
  }
  ["wp_user-settings-time"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "1447257892"
  }
  ["wp_dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "463"
  }
  ["twitter"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["facebook"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "pietergoosencom"
  }
  ["managenav-menuscolumnshidden"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(89) "a:4:{i:0;s:11:"link-target";i:1;s:11:"css-classes";i:2;s:3:"xfn";i:3;s:11:"description";}"
  }
  ["metaboxhidden_nav-menus"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(102) "a:4:{i:0;s:8:"add-post";i:1;s:14:"add-informasie";i:2;s:12:"add-post_tag";i:3;s:15:"add-post_format";}"
  }
  ["nav_menu_recently_edited"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "130"
  }
  ["closedpostboxes_page"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["metaboxhidden_page"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(94) "a:4:{i:0;s:10:"postcustom";i:1;s:16:"commentstatusdiv";i:2;s:7:"slugdiv";i:3;s:9:"authordiv";}"
  }
  ["closedpostboxes_post"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["metaboxhidden_post"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["closedpostboxes_positions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["metaboxhidden_positions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "a:0:{}"
  }
  ["rtladminbar"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "ltr"
  }
  ["session_tokens"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(285) "a:1:{s:64:"fa12574e7a42af2a8944d764c21bda64a5a5ee4572b1fbceb027d8b4af5afcd3";a:4:{s:10:"expiration";i:1448467488;s:2:"ip";s:3:"::1";s:2:"ua";s:108:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36";s:5:"login";i:1447257888;}}"
  }
}
```

So, if you need to display the description, you can do

```
echo $userdata['description'][0];
```

To learn how to reference values in an array, you should really need and go and learn the very basics of how arrays work and how to reference them

### EDIT

The following is an exact use case

```
$walt_id = 1; // Make sure you have the correct ID here
$userdata = get_user_meta( $walt_id );
echo $userdata['description'][0];
```

If this does not work, you have a serious issue somewhere which you should debug as I have stated in comments

Comment: @birgire thanks for the edit. The hand was faster than the brain there.

Comment: Thanks for the code on current_user. Actually, I have that info too, from the codex. I'm trying to display a specified user's info though. For example, on Page1, display user Walt Whitman's picture, description (bio), and social media links, regardless of who wrote the page or who is logged in reading the page.

Comment: @JustinMunce Then simply feed the user ID of Walt Whiteman to `get_user_meta()`. I do not understand what your issue is.

Comment: Hi Pieter, I apparently am unable to do that. Just spent another hour experimenting with _meta and _description code and haven't been able to make the bio display on the page, unfortunately

Comment: But I'm not trying to display the logged-in user's information. I'm trying to display the information for a specific user of the site "Walt Whitman's bio"

Comment: The `var_dump` will display **all** the info from Walt, so it is just a thing of using the correct property to display the info needed

Comment: I see that part of it. I can use: <?php $userdata = get_user_meta( '9999' ); ?><pre><?php var_dump( $userdata ); ?></pre><?php 
get_user_meta(); ?> to display the full meta info, but how do I cause it to display only the description?

Comment: See my update, hopefully it will help

Comment: Hi Pieter, thanks for that, I had got that far, but I don't seem to be able to display the description only. If I try  <?php $userdata = get_user_meta( 9999 ); ?><?php echo $userdata['description']; ?> I get the full print out of all meta. If I use <?php $user = wp_get_current_user( 9999 );
if ( $user->exists() )  // is_user_logged_in() is a wrapper for this line
    $userdata = get_user_meta( $user->data->ID );
    ?><pre><?php var_dump( $userdata ); ?></pre><?php echo $userdata['description'] ; ?> I get the full printout of all meta again. Not sure where my code is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I've tried without the var_dump. I've tried about 30 or so combinations of code that could conceivably work. I get either a full print out of all meta or various fatal errors (must be string, etc).

Comment: OK, I updated the question

Comment: Pieter, I very much appreciate all the code, but I just spent another hour trying to make this work and researching the functions involved and all I can do is display the bio of the person who wrote the page or the logged in user, not the bio of the person I want to display. If possible, could you please show an example code of what would work, and I could just adapt it?

Comment: Please get your facts straight now, you are confusing me. I fully tested my code this morning, it works, I can tell you that. Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme. You have a bug somewhere in a plugin or your theme

Comment: Yes, I'm sure your code works. I just don't know what to put on the page. You have provided several options, but I was hoping for something I can cut and paste, see work, and adapt, if possible

Comment: Is that exactly what I have done?

Comment: Somewhat, but the pieces of code are all separate. I don't know how to put them together so they display the bio.

Comment: See my final update. If that does not work, you have a bug or filter somewhere in your theme or in a plugin that is given you trouble

Comment: Thank you. That helped! I can now display things from the meta with slight adaptations of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_user_by` to get their User ID from the email address since it looks like that's the data you have available above. You can then use the [`get_userdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) or [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) from that user ID to pull all of their other meta fields.

### For example:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'useremail@gmail.com' );
$userdata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

$first_name = $userdata-> first_name;
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I use those commands to display the particular (bio) meta field for a given user ID?

Comment: [`get_usermeta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) return a whole wealth of info about the user including `description`. So, in the example above we would reference `$userdata->description` to get the bio field.

To call the userdata function to begin with just skip my first line and feed the ID into the `get_userdata` function.

Comment: Hi Mike, I understand get_usermeta and I am able to use it to display all a user's information. What I am not able to do is call up the user and display the bio / social media buttons. I don't know how to code it, in other words.

Comment: if when you dont have the field value but have the url for example if the slug `https://myexample.com/user/joe/` how to get value the slug

Answer (score 0):

(I am the op.)

Two options to solve this. These can be used to display any information for the users registered on your website. I'm going to show you how to display one OR two (ie more) things:

**1) Pieter Goosen way** (I checked his answer as correct above -- thanks again, Pieter) (People, you need to go into the user profile and get their user number. Use that number instead of 9999.

One thing:

```
<?php $walt_id = 9999; // Make sure you have the correct ID here
$userdata = get_user_meta( $walt_id );
echo $userdata['description'][0]; 
?>
```

More than one thing:

```
<?php $walt_id = 9999; // Make sure you have the correct ID here
$userdata = get_user_meta( $walt_id );
echo $userdata['description'][0]; 
echo $userdata['first_name'][0]; 
?>
```

**2) stephencottontail way:**

One thing:

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'user_description', 9999 ); ?> </br>
```

More than one thing:

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'user_description', 9999 ); ?> </br>
<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', 9999 ); ?>
```